# angular2 subject not subscribing the change

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-cli

I've two components and a shared service which is shared by the two components.

**shared.service.ts**

```
// ..... top level codes are skipped

private pickAnalysisForBubble = new Subject<any>();

  analysisForBubble$ = this.pickAnalysisForBubble.asObservable();

  mapToggleToPointOrBubble(value) {
    this.pickAnalysisForBubble.next(value);
  }
```

**utility.component.ts**

in view (utility.component.html), there are two radio button and one is pre-selected:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdbBubblePoint" class="rdbBubblePoint" value="Point" (change)="changeToPoint($event)"> Point<br>
<input type="radio" name="rdbBubblePoint" class="rdbBubblePoint" value="Bubble" (change)="changeToPoint($event)" checked="checked"> Bubble<br>
```

in component (utility.component.ts), there is a method to grab the click event: (I've imported the `shared.service` and added this as a provider.)

```
changeToPoint(event){
    # analysisInteraction is the shared service constructor
    this.analysisInteraction.mapToggleToPointOrBubble(event.target.value);
}
```

**map.component.ts**

I've imported the `shared.service` and added a constructor. Then in `ngOnInit` tried to `subscribe` the change, *but this is not working.*

```
# analysisInteraction is the shared service constructor
this.analysisInteraction.analysisForBubble$.subscribe(
        data => {
          this.DrawType = data;
          console.log("Drawtype fixed");
      });
```

I'm using `subject` to detect the change based on this [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service). What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you don't share the same instance of the service. Do you specify the corresponding provider when bootstrapping your application or within the main component:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
```

or

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ SharedService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  (...)
}
```

If you specify it within `providers` attributes of sub-components, you aren't sure to share the same instance...

**Edit**

Because of hierarchical injectors, each component will have its own instance and not share the same one. Thus, the shared service should be added as a provider in `main` Component. Also, thee shared service should not be included in the provider of sub-components.

Comment: Yes, I've added the `sharedService` as a provider in both my components.

Comment: I've added `sharedService` on my `main.ts` file also in my sub-components. Still not working. Any clue?

Comment: That's the problem ;-) In this case, each component will have its own instance and not share the same one. It's because of hierarchical injectors.

Comment: Please remove the providers from sub-components. They prevent things from working...

Comment: Yes it's working. Removing providers from my sub-components worked.